# Efficiently skipping parts of text to get to a token

Tags: haskell, parsec

While learning parsec, I find myself skipping large parts of a text rather often.
For instance:

```
manyTill anyChar (try $ string "Content-Type: text/plain;")
```

this is extremely common in my exercises with parsec. I do this all the time.
I generally skip large chunks of text to get to some other parts of text identified by a string or a char.

I was just wondering if the above line is efficient? "manyTill" function collects all the unneeded text that I'd like to skip. Even though I don't return it, "manyTill" still processes it into a list. I was expecting to have something like "skipManyTill" function or similar that would ignore chunks of text till it hits a certain token.

Am I confused or the above line is the common way of doing the skipping? Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just as a curiosity, if you write `skipManyTill` (it should not be too hard to implement!) and use it instead, do you get a significant performance increase?

Comment: @kqr This is exactly what I was wondering about. I would assume that it would be some performance increase and that is what I am questioning here.

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to try it for yourself! If you run into any trouble with writing the code for `skipManyTill`, you can post another question about that!

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, I'd suggest a multi-phase padre as being more idiomatic. Parse all of the HTTP headers into a `Map ByteString ByteString` and then decode that into your final data structure.